# AEM : How to get list of registered sling models using resource type

Tags: aem, sling, sling-models

While creating a sling model we can register it through a resource type. Is there any way through which we can get the sling model class name by providing resource type in AEM. For example : if i have a resource type /mysite/component/breadcrumb and sling model is BreadCrumbModel.java .
Is there OOTB service through which if i pass the resourceType value and get the class refernece.

Thanks

Comment: `org.apache.sling.models.factory.ModelFactory#createModel(@Nonnull Object adaptable, @Nonnull Class<ModelType> type) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, from either the provided `Resource` or `SlingHttpServletRequest` of the resource.

```
modelFactory.getModelFromResource(resource)
modelFactory.getModelFromRequest(request)
```

[ModelFactory API Docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/org/apache/sling/models/factory/ModelFactory.html#getModelFromResource(org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource))

Usage example:
If `SlingScriptHelper` is injected in your class -

```
Resource resource = resourceResolver.getResource("/mysite/component/breadcrumb");
slingScriptHelper.getService(ModelFactory.class).getModelFromResource(resource);
```

or if you already have `ModelFactory` injected and available, use it directly.

Comment: Thanks , it works. But one issue is some Models are using Resource as a adaptor where as some are using Request. Is there any way to check whether this Model belongs to resource or to request before getting resource ?

Comment: Glad it worked. To ascertain if model is adapted using request or resource, `exportModelForRequest` and `isModelAvailableForRequest` methods from `ModelFactory` look promising. I've not tested it though, you might want to give these methods a try.

Comment: curious, were you able to get it working, check if model is adapted using req or resource? which method helped you with that.

Comment: Yeah..through this i can check... Thanks mate. Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem since my request is coming through a servlet hence in that request it's not adapting the models register through a request. Because this request resource is different than actual resource. Anyways thanks for ur help :)

Comment: @SubSul `isModelAvailableForRequest` will check the model available for the resource embedded in the passed request. So, we can't check if the sling model of a component is adaptable from the request unless we have the request for that particular resource.
Also, in the latest sling models API, we have a method in `ModelFactory` named `getModelFromWrappedRequest` which wraps the request with the passed resource.

Comment: https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling10/org/apache/sling/models/factory/ModelFactory.html#getModelFromWrappedRequest-org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest-org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource-java.lang.Class-

AEM core component's BasePage model also uses the same method, but unfortunately, it wasn't working for me. I don't know the exact reason.